# Why is my answer wrong when expanding this expression

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm really new to Algebra and I have been having a bit of trouble understanding why my answer to a question is wrong?

In a paper I'm told to expand $-3q(4q-8)+2q^2(q+1)$ my answer is $-10q^2+24q+2q^3$, but the actual answer is $2q^3-10q^2+24q$.

Can someone please explain why my answer is slightly wrong. It looks like the actual answer has the terms arranged from smallest number to largest. A working out showing how I can get the answer would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The two expressions are equal, so there is no mistake. It tends to be conventional with polynomials that the expressions are ordered in decreasing powers, so that here the $q^3$ term would normally come first. It is because addition is commutative that the order doesn't affect the value of the expression.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkBennet, that was helpful.

Comment: So if the expression didn't contain any addition, you would avoid ordering them, since subtraction or division are not commutative.

Comment: I think of it as $(-10q^2)+(24q)+(2q^3)=(2q^3)+(-10q^2)+(24q)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually we get by expanding $$-12q^2+24q+2q^3+2q^2=-10q^2+24q+2q^3$$
your answer is right!